# Handsontable Scroll Bars Not Fitting to Div Size Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, handsontable

I am trying to get scroll bars activated for my Handsontable instances as per the following instructions.

https://docs.handsontable.com/0.31.2/demo-scrolling.html

However, when I specify the overflow:hidden css parameter for the handsontable container. The scroll bars do not adjust to the container size. I.e.

```
#equipment {
  /* scroll bars do not show up */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* I have also tried setting the height and width properties as suggested by the link above as well but this also causes strange things to happen */
}
```

I have created a js fiddle. See link below...

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/yxp192qL/28/

Does anyone know how I can get the scroll bars to work as intended?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Why not use `overflow: auto` ?

Comment: Because in the instructions from the software supplier said to use 'hidden'! But it seems what you have said fixed most of the problem. However, now when changing the size of the windows the horizontal scroll bar dissappears. Any ideas on that?

Comment: That's the default behavior of `overflow: auto`. The scrollbar will not show when the entire container is visible because there is nothing to scroll to. If you still want a scrollbar to show up, you would normally use `overflow: scroll` but it's not working on your example.

Answer (score -1):

i used 2 div different:
`that.tableData.addHook('afterScrollHorizontally', function (i, k) { var a = $("#div1 div div.wtHolder").scrollLeft(); $("#div2 div div.wtHolder").scrollLeft(a); })`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).